# PHP Compare keys and change certain values from a multidimensional array with corresponding keys' values from a simple array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays (one simple and one multidimensional) and I want to verify if certain keys from the multidimensional array have empty values and replace them with their correspondent values from the simple array.

Solution for both simple arrays and/or 2D arrays is here:

[PHP Compare and change certain elements in multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275940/php-compare-and-change-certain-elements-in-multidimensional-arrays/)

But what would be the solution in the situation above?

Example of simple array:

```
$superheroes_complete = array(
    1 => 'one',
    'two' => 'two',
    3 => 'three',
    'email' => 'peterparker@mail.com',
    5 => 'cinco',
    6 => 'six',
    'name' => 'Clark Kent',
    8 => 'eight'
);
```

Example of multidimensional array:

```
$superheroes_empty = array(
    "spiderman" => array(
        "name" => "Peter Parker",
        "email" => "",
    ),
    "superman" => array(
        "name" => "",
        "email" => "clarkkent@mail.com",
    ),
    "ironman" => array(
    "name" => "Harry Potter",
    "email" => "harrypotter@mail.com",
    )
);
```

Expectation:

```
$superheroes_empty = array(
    "spiderman" => array(
        "name" => "Peter Parker",
        "email" => "peterparker@mail.com",
    ),
    "superman" => array(
        "name" => "Clark Kent",
        "email" => "clarkkent@mail.com",
    ),
    "ironman" => array(
        "name" => "Harry Potter",
        "email" => "harrypotter@mail.com",
    )
);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So how is your simple array supposed to relate to the multidimensional array, to know which values to change? I can't see any relationship between the two, nor any explanation

Comment: The relation should be made according to their key names. Will compare which keys from multidimensional array are empty and will replace their values with correspondent values of keys from simple array. In the example above shoud replace the "name" and "email" keys' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using `array_walk_recursive`:

```
array_walk_recursive($superheroes_empty, function(&$v, $k) use ($superheroes_complete) {
    if ($v === '' && isset($superheroes_complete[$k])) {
        $v = $superheroes_complete[$k];
    }
});
```

This will fill in any empty values if a corresponding key is found in `$superheroes_complete`. Since this makes replacements by reference, it will directly change the `$superheroes_empty` array, so if you still need the one with empty values, make a copy before using this.

Comment: It's OK, I don't need the data from it. This is only an example. But is important that the `$superheroes_empty` to remain in initial structure after replacements are made. Is this possible though?

Comment: This won't change the structure; it will only full in empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
foreach($superheroes_empty as $key =>$array){
    foreach($array as $key1=>$data){        
        if(empty($data)){           
            $superheroes_empty[$key][$key1] = $superheroes_complete[$key1];         
            }
        }   
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($superheroes_empty);
```